# Manage several version of my app

Tags: android, git, version-control

I'm about to publish my Android app in the play store.
What is the best workflow to finally have 2 versions:

- The version I released, that I should correct some minors bugs.
- The next version which will have new features.

So I don't want to publish new features, just correct minor bugs.

I could just duplicate my code, but it will not be part of my Git Repository, so I don't like so much, I think it will soon be a mess.

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use git branches to maintain the two separate, er, branches.

I recommend this article, https://www.atlassian.com/git/workflows#!workflow-gitflow, to see a description of the Gitflow workflow model.

In your scenario, you'd have a Develop branch in which you develop new features, and a maintenance branch in which you'll correct the bugs.

Both branches will be part of the same Git Repository. No mess!